# Show $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^{5/2}}$ is $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

The task is to show $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^{5/2}}$$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with a continuous derivative.

---

Showing that the series converges at each point is easy, assume that has been shown.  Next I suppose I need to show that $f(x)$ is continuous.  My thought was to define $$f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^{5/2}},$$ and show that $f_N \to f(x)$ uniformly (then $f$ being continuous follows).

I think the following is a valid proof that $f_N \to f$ uniformly.  It suffices to show $|f_N(x) - f_M(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ when $N,M > $ some $Z \in \mathbb{Z},$ and assume $N > M.$
$$|f_N(x) - f_M(x)| = \sum_{n=M+1}^N \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^{5/2}} < \sum_{n=M+1}^N n^{-2} < \epsilon$$ 
for large enough $M,N.$

---

The part I am stuck on is showing $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$
Rudin's book states that if

> $f_n$ are differentiable
>   $f'_n$ uniformly converge
>   $f_n(x_0)$ converges for some point $x_0$
>   Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly and $f' = \lim f'_n(x)$

I am wondering if there is an easier way to show that $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable? And if not, would showing $f'_n$ converge uniformly be the same as above - using a Cauchy sequence for $f'_n$'s?

Comment: As another user190080 noted, you may use the Weierstrass M-test to prove uniform convergence. You have essentially provided a proof for this fact via Cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence with $M_n=n^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could use the [Weierstrass-M-criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to show that the above sequence is converging uniformly, just observe that 
$$
\bigg|\frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n^{5/2}}\bigg|\leq\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}
$$
and furthermore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}=\xi(\frac 5 2)<\infty
$$
hence while using the above criterion you can infer that the sequence
$$
f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin{nx}}{n^{5/2}}
$$
converges absolutely and uniformly to some $f$.

For the differentiability part I'd suggest the same as you already mentioned (just again, use the Weierstrass criterion, it will also work).